# Problem parsing Array of Objects in the backend. Parsed as [Object Object] by nodeJS

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, mongodb

The POST request body looks like this:

```
    "products": [
        {
            "_id":"5ff08842b6145209e4941f56",
            "quantity": 2
        }
    ],
    "frequency":1,
    "deliveryDay": "EVERYDAY",
    "amount": 660
}
```

The endpoint handling this request is:

```
export const createSubscriptionTemplate = async (req, res, next) => {
  validationErrorHandler(req, next);
  const {products, frequency, deliveryDay, amount} = req.body;
  const productsArr = [];
  try {
    for (const product of products) {
    const prod = await Product.findById(product._id);
    productsArr.push({_id: prod._id, productName: prod.title, quantity: product.quantity});
  }
  const subscriptionTemplate = new SubscriptionTemplate({
    products: productsArr,
    frequency: frequency,
    deliveryDay: deliveryDay,
    amount: amount
  });
    const result = await subscriptionTemplate.save();
    res.status(201).json({
      message: 'New Subscription created',
      result: result
    });
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err);
  }
};
```

When I tried to log the product inside the loop it shows **[Object Object]**, so when this endpoint is hit the error it gives is:

```
{
    "message": "Cannot read property '_id' of null"
}
```

because **_id** cannot be parsed from **[Object Object]**

I am using NodeJS as a backend and MongoDB as a database.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this? Very much thanks in advance.

Comment: node will log objects that way, that's not conclusive.  you should log `JSON.stringify(obj)` or use `util.inspect` to see what you actually have

Comment: ```JSON.stringify(product)``` inside the for loop logs this single square bracket ```"["```

Comment: Problem might be here `const prod = await Product.findById(product._id);`, check if (prod) available  or not

Comment: Hi @Naren, the product already exists in the Database, but the Line that you pointed at gives the error. Inside the loop when I use ```product._id``` the product could not be found because ```product._id``` could not be extracted from ```[object Object]```. Thanks for narrowing it down, but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

You can log the result as JSON.stringify(obj), to display the object. If you want to pretty-print, you can write: JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2). If you get an error, saying "JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures" then just pass a function as a second parameter.

```js
var cache = [];
JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => {
  if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
    // Duplicate reference found, discard key
    if (cache.includes(value)) return;

    // Store value in our collection
    cache.push(value);
  }
  return value;
});
```

This function will skip over circular references and add all non-circular references to a cache array. It will then stringify everything in the cache array. Make sure to replace "obj" with your object.

Otherwise, you can use util.inspect().

```js
var util = require('util');
util.inspect(obj);
```

Which will also serialize your object, again, commonly used for logs.

Comment: Hi Daniel, embedded your snippet inside the ```for loop```, logging ```cache``` returns an empty array ```[]``` and ```JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)``` logs ```"[" "O" "b" "j" "e" "c" "t" "O" "b" "j" "e" "c" "t" "]"```.

Comment: Hi @CaffeinatedDeveloper, if util.inspect() doesn't work, there might be a problem with your backend. I have posted the edit above.